# persist sj:datepicker as timestamp

Tags: java, sql, persistence, struts2-jquery

I have an input field:

```
<sj:datepicker readonly="true" name="exam.endDate" required="true" timepicker="true" timepickerAmPm="true" />
```

where exam.endDate is a java.sql.Timestamp object with appropriate getter and setter. Exam is an entity being stored in a table and the column for endDate is of type TIMESTAMP. When i persist an exam entity and later retrieve it, all my values are dates only and times are displayed as 00:00. How do i store the time component as well?

This is how I'm displaying the date:

```
<s:date name="exam.endDate" format="dd/MM HH:mm" />
```

And i get something like: "24/06 00:00"

I know that the parameter interceptors aren't working right because when i print out `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(exam.endDate)` as soon as i enter the action and it prints out 00:00 no matter what i input.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the struts2 parameter interceptor does not handle timestamps, so I need to write my own.

```
public class MyTimeStampConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("<!--Desired Format here-->");

    @Override
    public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) throws TypeConversionException {
        try{
               if (values == null || values.length == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
               return new java.sql.Timestamp(sdf.parse(values[0]).getTime());
        }catch(Exception e){        
            throw new TypeConversionException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToString(Map context, Object object)  throws TypeConversionException  {
        try{
            if(object instanceof Timestamp){
                return sdf.format(new Date(((Timestamp)object).getTime()));
            }
            return "";
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new TypeConversionException(e);
        }
    }

}
```